# Troubleshooting SQLiteException (unable to open database file)

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the databasehelper class. I amtrying to get a string from database stored in mTable.

```
public class KamaDBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

private  Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
//private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

private static String TABLE="mTable";
private static String DB_NAME="mdb12.db";
private static String ROW_ID="_id";
public static String ROW_QUOTES= "quote";
private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.android/databases/";

public  KamaDBAdapter(Context context) 
{
super(context,DB_NAME,null,2);
 this.mContext = context;
//mDb = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
}
/*public KamaDBAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
{
this.createDatabase();
return this;
}*/

public  void readDataBase() 
{
this.getReadableDatabase();



}
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

public void close() 
{
mDb.close();
}
public  String retriveData()
{


Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE, new String[] {ROW_ID},null , null, null, null, null);
//mCursor.moveToFirst();
String mReturn = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID));

mCursor.close();
return mReturn;


}
public boolean checkdatabase()  {

  SQLiteDatabase mCheckDataBase = null;
    try
    {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mCheckDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,    

 SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException mSQLiteException)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "DatabaseNotFound " + mSQLiteException.toString());
    }

    if(mCheckDataBase != null)
    {
        mCheckDataBase.close();
    }
    return mCheckDataBase != null;
}
public void copydatabase() throws IOException {

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myinput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

// transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
{
    myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
}

//Close the streams
myoutput.flush();
myoutput.close();
myinput.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And Main Activity code is.

```
public class DbActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static KamaDBAdapter mDbHelper=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDbHelper = new KamaDBAdapter(this);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
   boolean b= mDbHelper.checkdatabase();
   if(b==true)
   {
    mDbHelper.readDataBase();
    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
    try {
        mDbHelper.copydatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new Error("Unable to copy database");
    }

    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  String s=  mDbHelper.retriveData();
    tv.setText(s);

}
}
```

I m getting error:

```
09-23 17:29:17.872: ERROR/Database(2658): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.android.android/databases/mdb12.db", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
09-23 17:29:17.882: ERROR/TAG(2658): DatabaseNotFound android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Sunny, that was a terrible title.

Comment: sorry for that Mat but right now i m feeling irritate.

Comment: Are you sure of the path `com.android.android`.?

Comment: yes.The path is exactly com.android.android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
DB_NAME="mdb12";
```

Also unless you are working for `android.com`

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.android/databases/";
```

is probably wrong. Put correct package name(you can check it from your manifest file)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
DB_NAME="mdb12.sqlite";
```

instead of

```
DB_NAME="mdb12.db";
```

Comment: this is not working i changed the extension :(

Comment: but had you originally create ".sqlite" file or by just renaming?

Comment: originally craeted in sqlite browser.

Comment: so just delete old(.db) from assets folder and copy new one(.sqlite) and refresh it and clean, then tyr

Comment: had you added permission in manifest file (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead of ......

public  void readDataBase()

{

this.getReadableDatabase();

}

Change and try........

public  void readDataBase()

{

```
SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        db_Read.close();
```

}